# creating endpoint for scikit learn model in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I have want to create an endpoint for scikit learn logistic regression model inside sagemaker. I have scikit learn code inside a file called `scikitlogistic.py`. The below code is contained in `scikitlogistic.py`

```
import subprocess as sb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle,json
import sys
def install(package):
sb.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
install('s3fs')
if __name__ =='__main__':

    train_data = 's3://{}/{}/{}'.format(bucket, prefix, 'train') #train_data
    outputlocation = 's3://{}/{}/{}'.format(bucket, prefix, 'logistic_scikit')


    os.environ["Train"]=train_data
    os.environ["SM_MODEL_DIR"]='s3://<bucket>/<prefix>/model_dir'
    os.environ["SM_OUTPUT_DIR"]=outputlocation


    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # hyperparameters sent by the client are passed as command-line arguments to the script.
    parser.add_argument('--solver', type=str, default='liblinear')

    # Data, model, and output directories
    parser.add_argument('--output_data_dir', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_OUTPUT_DIR'))
    parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_MODEL_DIR'))
    parser.add_argument('--train', type=str, default=os.environ.get('Train'))

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

df = pd.read_csv(args.train)#writing my data into pandas data frame

y = df.Class
X = df.drop('Class', axis=1)


solver = args.solver
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression(solver=solver).fit(X_train, y_train)

#creating model.joblib folder
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object(<bucket>,"<prefix>/model_dir/model.joblib")
object.put(Body=b'abc')

from sklearn.externals import joblib
if __name__=='__main__':
    joblib.dump(lr, '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/<notebookinstancename>/model.joblib')
```

In my jupyter notebook I have written the following code to train my model on scikit logistic

```
role = <role>

region = boto3.Session().region_name

bucket = <bucket> 
prefix = <prefix> 

train_data = 's3://{}/{}/{}'.format(bucket, prefix, 'train')
train_channel = sagemaker.session.s3_input(train_data, content_type='text/csv')

output_path = 's3://{}/{}/{}'.format(bucket, prefix,'output_data_dir')

from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn
sklearn = SKLearn(
    entry_point='scikitlogistic.py',
    train_instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge",
    role=role, train_instance_count=1,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker.Session(),output_path=output_path,
    hyperparameters={'solver':'liblinear'})
```

Now I'm fitting it

```
sklearn.fit({'train': train_channel})
```

When I'm trying to fit the model it is throwing `ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>` at `df = pd.read_csv(args.train)` in `scikitlogistic.py`.

```
2019-12-04 12:31:17 Starting - Starting the training job...
2019-12-04 12:31:18 Starting - Launching requested ML instances......
2019-12-04 12:32:25 Starting - Preparing the instances for training...
2019-12-04 12:33:11 Downloading - Downloading input data...
2019-12-04 12:33:41 Training - Downloading the training image..
2019-12-04 12:34:16 Uploading - Uploading generated training model
2019-12-04 12:34:16 Failed - Training job failed
2019-12-04 12:34:01,194 sagemaker-containers INFO     Imported framework sagemaker_sklearn_container.training
2019-12-04 12:34:01,196 sagemaker-containers INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
2019-12-04 12:34:01,206 sagemaker_sklearn_container.training INFO     Invoking user training script.
2019-12-04 12:34:03,100 sagemaker-containers INFO     Module scikitlogistic does not provide a setup.py. 
Generating setup.py
2019-12-04 12:34:03,101 sagemaker-containers INFO     Generating setup.cfg
2019-12-04 12:34:03,101 sagemaker-containers INFO     Generating MANIFEST.in
2019-12-04 12:34:03,101 sagemaker-containers INFO     Installing module with the following command:
/miniconda3/bin/python -m pip install . 
Processing /opt/ml/code
Building wheels for collected packages: scikitlogistic
  Building wheel for scikitlogistic (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for scikitlogistic (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for scikitlogistic: filename=scikitlogistic-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=7186 sha256=3a209b33ea1fba4843ad74565d16764ebc3c18b5c0b68ea4e7aa0fe4e31960c0
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-rh9bcece/wheels/35/24/16/37574d11bf9bde50616c67372a334f94fa8356bc7164af8ca3
Successfully built scikitlogistic
Installing collected packages: scikitlogistic
Successfully installed scikitlogistic-1.0.0
2019-12-04 12:34:04,479 sagemaker-containers INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
2019-12-04 12:34:04,490 sagemaker-containers INFO     Invoking user script

Training Env:

{
    "additional_framework_parameters": {},
    "channel_input_dirs": {
        "train": "/opt/ml/input/data/train"
    },
    "current_host": "algo-1",
    "framework_module": "sagemaker_sklearn_container.training:main",
    "hosts": [
        "algo-1"
    ],
    "hyperparameters": {
        "solver": "liblinear"
    },
    "input_config_dir": "/opt/ml/input/config",
    "input_data_config": {
        "train": {
            "TrainingInputMode": "File",
            "S3DistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
            "RecordWrapperType": "None"
        }
    },
    "input_dir": "/opt/ml/input",
    "is_master": true,
    "job_name": "sagemaker-scikit-learn-2019-12-04-12-31-17-192",
    "log_level": 20,
    "master_hostname": "algo-1",
    "model_dir": "/opt/ml/model",
    "module_dir": "s3://sagemaker2222/sagemaker-scikit-learn-2019-12-04-12-31-17-192/source/sourcedir.tar.gz",
    "module_name": "scikitlogistic",
    "network_interface_name": "eth0",
    "num_cpus": 4,
    "num_gpus": 0,
    "output_data_dir": "/opt/ml/output/data",
    "output_dir": "/opt/ml/output",
    "output_intermediate_dir": "/opt/ml/output/intermediate",
    "resource_config": {
        "current_host": "algo-1",
        "hosts": [
            "algo-1"
        ],
        "network_interface_name": "eth0"
    },
    "user_entry_point": "scikitlogistic.py"
}

Environment variables:

SM_HOSTS=["algo-1"]
SM_NETWORK_INTERFACE_NAME=eth0
SM_HPS={"solver":"liblinear"}
SM_USER_ENTRY_POINT=scikitlogistic.py
SM_FRAMEWORK_PARAMS={}
SM_RESOURCE_CONFIG={"current_host":"algo-1","hosts":["algo-1"],"network_interface_name":"eth0"}
SM_INPUT_DATA_CONFIG={"train":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"}}
SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR=/opt/ml/output/data
SM_CHANNELS=["train"]
SM_CURRENT_HOST=algo-1
SM_MODULE_NAME=scikitlogistic
SM_LOG_LEVEL=20
SM_FRAMEWORK_MODULE=sagemaker_sklearn_container.training:main
SM_INPUT_DIR=/opt/ml/input
SM_INPUT_CONFIG_DIR=/opt/ml/input/config
SM_OUTPUT_DIR=/opt/ml/output
SM_NUM_CPUS=4
SM_NUM_GPUS=0
SM_MODEL_DIR=/opt/ml/model
SM_MODULE_DIR=s3://sagemaker2222/sagemaker-scikit-learn-2019-12-04-12-31-17-192/source/sourcedir.tar.gz
SM_TRAINING_ENV={"additional_framework_parameters":{},"channel_input_dirs":{"train":"/opt/ml/input/data/train"},"current_host":"algo-1","framework_module":"sagemaker_sklearn_container.training:main","hosts":["algo-1"],"hyperparameters":{"solver":"liblinear"},"input_config_dir":"/opt/ml/input/config","input_data_config":{"train":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"}},"input_dir":"/opt/ml/input","is_master":true,"job_name":"sagemaker-scikit-learn-2019-12-04-12-31-17-192","log_level":20,"master_hostname":"algo-1","model_dir":"/opt/ml/model","module_dir":"s3://sagemaker2222/sagemaker-scikit-learn-2019-12-04-12-31-17-192/source/sourcedir.tar.gz","module_name":"scikitlogistic","network_interface_name":"eth0","num_cpus":4,"num_gpus":0,"output_data_dir":"/opt/ml/output/data","output_dir":"/opt/ml/output","output_intermediate_dir":"/opt/ml/output/intermediate","resource_config":{"current_host":"algo-1","hosts":["algo-1"],"network_interface_name":"eth0"},"user_entry_point":"scikitlogistic.py"}
SM_USER_ARGS=["--solver","liblinear"]
SM_OUTPUT_INTERMEDIATE_DIR=/opt/ml/output/intermediate
SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN=/opt/ml/input/data/train
SM_HP_SOLVER=liblinear
PYTHONPATH=/miniconda3/bin:/miniconda3/lib/python37.zip:/miniconda3/lib/python3.7:/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload:/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages

Invoking script with the following command:

/miniconda3/bin/python -m scikitlogistic --solver liblinear


Collecting s3fs
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/5c/ec84c7ec49fde2c3b0d885ecae4504fa40fc77fef7684e9f2939c50f9b94/s3fs-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: boto3>=1.9.91 in /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from s3fs) (1.10.6)
Collecting fsspec>=0.6.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/04/1e/6108c48f2d4ad9ef1a6bff01fb58245c009f37b2bd0505ec6d0f55cc326d/fsspec-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (62kB)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore>=1.12.91 in /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from s3fs) (1.13.6)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.3.0,>=0.2.0 in /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from boto3>=1.9.91->s3fs) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from boto3>=1.9.91->s3fs) (0.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1; python_version >= "2.7" in /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore>=1.12.91->s3fs) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils<0.16,>=0.10 in /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore>=1.12.91->s3fs) (0.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.26,>=1.20; python_version >= "3.4" in /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore>=1.12.91->s3fs) (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1; python_version >= "2.7"->botocore>=1.12.91->s3fs) (1.12.0)
Installing collected packages: fsspec, s3fs
Successfully installed fsspec-0.6.1 s3fs-0.4.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/ml/code/scikitlogistic.py", line 101, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(args.train)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 440, in _read
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 224, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>
2019-12-04 12:34:06,008 sagemaker-containers ERROR    ExecuteUserScriptError:
Command "/miniconda3/bin/python -m scikitlogistic --solver liblinear"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnexpectedStatusException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-bfad3082f107> in <module>()
----> 1 sklearn.fit({'train': train_data})

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in fit(self, inputs, wait, logs, job_name)
    339         self.latest_training_job = _TrainingJob.start_new(self, inputs)
    340         if wait:
--> 341             self.latest_training_job.wait(logs=logs)
    342 
    343     def _compilation_job_name(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in wait(self, logs)
    902         """
    903         if logs:
--> 904             self.sagemaker_session.logs_for_job(self.job_name, wait=True)
    905         else:
    906             self.sagemaker_session.wait_for_job(self.job_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in logs_for_job(self, job_name, wait, poll)
   1513 
   1514         if wait:
-> 1515             self._check_job_status(job_name, description, "TrainingJobStatus")
   1516             if dot:
   1517                 print()

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in _check_job_status(self, job, desc, status_key_name)
   1154                 ),
   1155                 allowed_statuses=["Completed", "Stopped"],
-> 1156                 actual_status=status,
   1157             )
   1158 

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job sagemaker-scikit-learn-2019-12-04-12-31-17-192: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: ExecuteUserScriptError:
Command "/miniconda3/bin/python -m scikitlogistic --solver liblinear"
```

I'm sure that path of file is valid. I'm not sure what is causing the error. Can someone please tell what mistake I might have done in `scikitlogistic.py`? Also I couldn't find good resources about deploying scikit learn models in sagemaker, other than AWS docs. Can someone guide me to some good resources?

Answer (score 0):

the S3 channels are created in environment variables as `SM_CHANNEL_{channel name}` - see [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/docker-container-environmental-variables-user-scripts.html)

so I suggest you try replacing `os.environ.get('Train')` by `os.environ.get('SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN')`